# How to solve execution time issue of AppScripts for non-G suite users?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I have an attendance system which is working fine for G suite users (execution time is 30 minutes) but I want to make it running for all gmail users (execution time 6 minutes). When a teacher presses a specific menu at my Google Sheets page, it allows students to report their attendance from an Android App to Google Sheet for 10 minutes.

> The whole code is working fine for G Suite Users but I want to make it
> for all Gmail users. I tried to execute it from a regular Gmail but it
> shows Timed Out at the end.

I have the following two lines of code for students to have 10 minutes to respond:

```
function refreshSheet(){

  //Few other lines of codes are here

  var val = dashboard.getRange("C6").getValue(); //C6 is a dropdown list in Sheets of "Start 1-Period" and "Start 2-Period"
  if (val == "Start 1-Period"){ ScriptApp.newTrigger("onePeriod").timeBased().after(10*60*1000).create();}
  if (val == "Start 2-Period"){ ScriptApp.newTrigger("twoPeriod").timeBased().after(10*60*1000).create();}
  
  //These few lines of codes below within the refreshSheet() should be executed after the above called trigger and its function execution.

  for (var i=0; i<students.length; i++) {
      if (students[i][0] !== '') ss.removeEditor(students[i][0].toString());
  } 
  
  protectionm.remove();  
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}

function onePeriod(){}

function twoPeriod(){}
```

I reviewed few posts here but none of them is working for me. How can I solve it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Tag Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There are two things you can do:

1. **If you deploy your script as a [WebApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app), you can execute it as "You" - that is the user from a GSuite domain who has an execution limit of 30 min.**
2. **Design your script in a different way.**

- Instead of waiting 10 minutes with `Utilities.sleep()`, incorporate a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers)
- You can do so with the [trigger builder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder)
- This means - end the current function and specify that the continuation of the script (embedded in the second function) will start running 10 minutes later
- The time inbetween will not count as execution time and will not lead to a timeout.

Sample:

```js
function myFirstFunction(){
// do something
//now set-up the trigger:
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("mySecondFunction").timeBased().after(10*60*1000).create();
}

// will be called after the amount of seconds specified in `after()`
function mySecondFunction(){
//now implement the rest of your code
}
```

Comment: It is not working for me. Sorry. Please check my revised code at the post.

Comment: the trigger is not created at all. Is there any issue in the code?

Comment: Did you run `refreshSheet()` manually and the trigger has not been created after this? Check under`Edit->Current project's triggers`. If the trigger has not been created likely your `if` statement has not been fullfilled. Check by implementing some logs into your `if`statement.