# How to add users as editors to a spreadsheet in one function and remove them in another function?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to add a number of users (students) as editors to a spreadsheet in function refreshSheet() and after 5 minutes I want to remove them in another function onePeriod(). The code works fine if I add and remove the users in the same function but does not work in two different functions.

> Please note that I have 2-5 permanent editors of the spreadsheet that
> I don't want to delete. Only those students need to remove which I
> added in the refreshSheet() function.

My codes are:

```
function refreshSheet(){
  var sheet1 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('StudentList');
  
  //Need to bring all students emails from Column of StudentList sheet to students array. 
  var data = sheet1.getLastRow();
  var students = [];
  var students = sheet1.getRange(2, 6, data).getValues();  
  
  var ssId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId);
  for (var i=0; i<students.length; i++){ // you are looping through rows and selecting the 1st and only column index
     if (students[i][0] !== '') ss.addEditor(students[i][0].toString()); 
  }  

  //Utilities.sleep(300000); Not the problem at all
}

// Removing all the student editors from the spreadsheet
function onePeriod(){
  for (var i=0; i<students.length; i++) {
      if (students[i][0] !== '') ss.removeEditor(students[i][0].toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the point in the sleep? It just stalls the program for 5 minutes and then ends?

Comment: Marked as duplicate of [How to solve execution time issue of AppScripts for non-G suite users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65167275/how-to-solve-execution-time-issue-of-appscripts-for-non-g-suite-users) - you asked this two days ago!

Comment: @RafaGuillermo he asked it but I think his question was more general than this one and he couldn't apply it to the specific problem. Maybe it is a duplicate, but believe me it is not as much duplicate as half of the posts people are asking here. Yesterday, someone asked how to copy values from one sheet to another and he got a clear upvoted answer while the question should be closed in the first place. My point is, if this is a duplicate question, then we should close 2k and more questions that are as much duplicates as this one. I might be wrong and excuse me for that but that's my opinion.

Comment: @Marios I just thought that if a user asks two times the same question - it does not make so much sense to provide again the same answer...

Comment: @ziganotschka thanks for your feedback. The question here is not the `Utilities.sleep(300000);` as it was in his previous question. OP has a different issue here: he wants to execute two separate functions with a sleeper in between the calls. It might be obvious to us, but it might not be obvious to him.

Comment: @Marios Utilities.sleep(300000) is not any issue here. It is totally different question. I need to add a group of students as editors in one function and then remove the same group of students from another function. Please note that I have 2-5 permanent editors which I do not want to remove.

Comment: @TamjidTaha we are on the same page, no worries. Anyway, I made my answer a community wiki post. So other people can contribute to the answer and the question can be closed if they feel to. @TamjidTaha check my answer. I am not using `Utilities.sleep(300000);` .

Comment: @Marios, the problem is not the 5 minutes sleeping. Please forget the sleep function. It is showing error in the onePeriod() that var students are not defined.

Comment: @TamjidTaha check my updated answer. You forgot to define students in the `onePeriod` function. You can either do it like my answer, or put these lines of code as global variables outside of any function. But please, next time when you have a question. Make **clear** what the issue is and how your question is not the same as the previous one you asked. In this way you don't cause confusion to the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Modification 1:

The issue in your code is that you haven't defined `students` in the `onePeriod` function:

```
function onePeriod(){
  for (var i=0; i<students.length; i++) {
      if (students[i][0] !== '') ss.removeEditor(students[i][0].toString());
  }
}
```

Since `students` is scoped in another function, it can't be used within `onePeriod` or any other function. You can either define again students within `onePeriod` as I do in the solution below, or define it as a global variable so it can be used in both `refreshSheet` and `onePeriod`.

### Modification 2:

> I have 2-5 permanent editors of the spreadsheet that I don't want to
> delete.

Then define an array of the students you **don't** want to delete and exclude them from the `if` condition:

```
function onePeriod(){
    var exclude_students = ['name1','name2','name3']; // put students you don't want to delete as editors
    var sheet1 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('StudentList');
    var data = sheet1.getLastRow();
    var students = [];
    var students = sheet1.getRange(2, 6, data).getValues();   
  for (var i=0; i<students.length; i++) {
      if (students[i][0] !== '' && !exclude_students.includes(students[i][0])) ss.removeEditor(students[i][0].toString());
  }
}
```

### Modification 3 similar to [ziganotschka`s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65179166/11225291):

Instead of **pausing** your code, you can create a scheduled trigger for `onePeriod` to be executed after 5 minutes:

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("onePeriod")
 .timeBased()
 .after(5 * 60 * 1000) // create trigger to execute onePeriod after 5 minutes
 .create();
```

I also added a code to delete any triggers associated with this function, so you clear the previous triggers before you create a new one.

### Solution:

```
function refreshSheet(){
  var sheet1 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('StudentList');
  
  //Need to bring all students emails from Column of StudentList sheet to students array. 
  var data = sheet1.getLastRow();
  var students = [];
  var students = sheet1.getRange(2, 6, data).getValues();  
  
  var ssId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId);
  for (var i=0; i<students.length; i++){ // you are looping through rows and selecting the 1st and only column index
     if (students[i][0] !== '') ss.addEditor(students[i][0].toString()); 
  }  
  createTrigger();
}

// Removing all the student editors from the spreadsheet except for some
function onePeriod(){
    var exclude_students = ['name1','name2','name3']; // put students you don't want to delete as editors
    var sheet1 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('StudentList');
    var data = sheet1.getLastRow();
    var students = [];
    var students = sheet1.getRange(2, 6, data).getValues();   
  for (var i=0; i<students.length; i++) {
      if (students[i][0] !== '' && !exclude_students.includes(students[i][0])) ss.removeEditor(students[i][0].toString());
  }
} 


function createTrigger() {
  Trigger_delete();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("onePeriod")
  .timeBased()
  .after(5 * 60 * 1000) // create trigger to execute onePeriod after 5 minutes
  .create();  
}


function Trigger_delete(){
var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
  if (triggers[i].getHandlerFunction() == "onePeriod") {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
  }
} 
}
```

**Note:**

You only need to execute the function `refreshSheet()`:

[image]